# How does cakePHP naming convention work?

Tags: cakephp

I'm relatively new to PHP. Started learning PHP, but then come across cakePHP, which is suppose to speed up development time.

After reading the documentation and blog tutorial I still don't understand the naming convention. I guess I won't know until I start to do some examples, but to get me started can someone please explain to me how cakePHP associate database tables to the controller/model layer?

The below code is an abstract from the tutorial. It is a controller method that passes the post id to the view layer. The database table is called "posts". $this->Post refers to the model class of Post, which correlates to the plural form of posts in the database.

```
public function view($id = null) {
  $this->Post->id = $id;
  $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
}
```

OK I get that. Then, in the documentation it refers to the following correlation:

**ReallyBigPerson and really_big_people**

So it seems like the correlation actually follows the rule in English semantics. Does this mean that cakePHP has a list of singular and plural words hidden somewhere that it works from? For example can I use the below correlation without breaking the code?

**This and these** or **Man and men** or **Foot and feet** or **Moose and moose** or **Goose and geese**

Furthermore, if I have both singular and plural form of tables in my database, will it break the code, or will it just associate to the plural-formed table?

Just find it baffling... Why couldn't they just match the naming convention like for like with prefixes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Inflector

CakePHP uses its `Inflector` class to determine the plurals of things.

Since the naming conventions dictate that model names are singular and tables names are pluralised, it uses the inflector to apply English semantics / rules to determine the plural.

If you need some help understanding the output of the Inflector, you can use the [CakePHP inflector website](http://inflector.cakephp.org).

## Pluralisation Examples

```
Model name: Post
Table name: posts

Model name: User
Table name: users

Model name: Sheep
Table name: sheep

Model name: News
Table name: news

Model name: Radius
Table name: radii
```

Check the Inflector site to be sure.

## Non-standard Table names

While CakePHP offers a standard rule set for naming and conventions, none of it is set in stone. If you want to change the name of the table used for a particular model, simply specify the table name in the model:

```
class Thing extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'somethings';
}
```

Or, if you want a model that does not use a table:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = null;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this answer is succinct and straight to the point +1 answered.