# How to tell cake bake that I'm not using name convention?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table called **professores** and i created a modal called **Professor** because in Brazil thats the right singular form for this word.
I need use cake bake to create controller with (add, edit, delete etc) to make my life easier.
When i do:

```
cake bake controller professores
```

He says that i dont have a model because hes looking for a model called **Professore**.

What is the best practice to deal with this issue??

My model **Professor** i used `public $useTable = 'professores'` to tell to the model that I'm using table **professores** instead **professors**.
How can i tell to cake bake that **ProfessoresController** to use **Professor** model. Even if i decide create controller by myself how to deal with this.

resuming, i need use this names:

```
Table: professores
Model: Professor.php
Controller: ProfessoresController.php
```

Comment: I guess the most straightforward answer would be to use English names. Although I guess the pluralization can be influenced *somewhere*

Comment: i can't use english for that and cakephp probably have something flexible for this cases

Comment: The class in question seems to be named `ClassInflector`. http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Inflector.html Also see [How does cakePHP naming convention work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11876170) and http://blog.framethrower.de/content/cakephp-naming-conventions-and-mighty-inflector - no hint that the inflector can be easily replaced, though.

Comment: A German-language article suggests that inflections can be edited in `/config/inflections.php`, maybe worth checking out

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is to *still* use english names for controllers - as for the rest of your coding and application. You then use custom routing to map it to /professores as you want it to. Clean and simple. Dont fight the framework.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html